# SQL QUALIFY in multiple table joins

Tags: sql, database, subquery, inner-join, teradata

I'm working on teammate's SQL code that retrieves data from 3 tables. The query structure looks like below.

Each time I run the query, the results are slightly different. SELECT COUNT(*) varies in thousands with total number of rows in millions.

My guess is that the QUALIFY clause may impact the results. Is there anything I can do to improve it and make sure each time the result is the same?

```
SELECT
    t1.acct_number,
    min(t1.date)
FROM (
    SELECT
        a.status_code,
        a.date,
        a.token_nb,
        b.acct_number,
        c.source_code,
    FROM table a

        (SELECT
            acct_id,
            acct_number,
        FROM
            table b
        WHERE product_code = '10'
        GROUP BY 1,2) b

        (SELECT
            request_id,
            service_number,
        FROM
            table c
        WHERE date IS NOT NULL
        AND service_number LIKE ANY ('%apple','juice')
        GROUP BY 1,2) c

    WHERE a.acct_id = b.acct_id
    AND a.request_id = c.request_id
    AND a.date > '2023-05-01'
    AND a.status_code = '00'
    QUALIFY (row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY a.token_nb ORDER BY a.creation_date) ASC = 1)
)t1 
GROUP BY 1
```

I have also tried to break the multiple tables on the FROM line into separate views. I have created views for each table a,b,c, applied conditions (WHERE and QUALITY) for each table at view level, then INNER JOIN all views together. The final results are even more different than what I expected.

My guess is that multiple tables on FROM line doesn't always mean INNER JOIN all tables. Should I use LEFT JOIN somewhere?

Thank you!

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: BTW, the query above has several syntax errors.

Comment: The row_number can change the actual rows returned (if the order by is not unique) but not the number of rows. Must be something else ...